# With a true random number generator at hand, how to implement one-time pad?

Tags: random-number-generator, one-time-pad

I have a Raspberry Pi single-board computer that happened to have an hardware true random number generator, based on some quantum effects on the processor silicon, baked into its BCM2835 chip and I can pump its randomness by dumping bits from `/dev/hwrng` device in Raspbian, its Debian-based Linux operating system.

Now let's say I want to implement some sort of one-time pad scheme using this little piece of hardware as a randomness generator. How?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70386/discussion-on-question-by-maxthon-chan-with-a-true-random-number-generator-at-ha).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four concerns here:

1. Pad generation
2. Pad transmission
3. Message privacy
4. Message authenticity

**Pad generation**

The security of the one-time pad depends on the assumption that the pads are generated from a truly random source.

This is actually quite a big ask. Suppose for a moment that you want to exchange a 4 gigabyte pad. Let's say your RNG does that one byte at a time. What you're basically asking is for *billions* of iterations of the RNG without any kind of generation failure.

Worse, the RNG can fail in a way that is not immediately obvious or detectable. The Debian bug springs to mind here.

Or, more directly, a nation state could deliberately weaken your RNG.

**Pad Transmission**

The next problem is finding a secure way to transfer the pad. The pad will be longer than the message you wish to transmit, at least if you want to be able to detect alterations to your message. See below.

This immediately raises the question of what one hopes to gain by using the OTP. If you have a secure channel capable of transmitting a pad *longer* than the original message, why not just use this channel to transmit the message?

Given this logic, there is only really one use for the OTP, which is to time-shift a secure channel. For example, I might be able to meet my friend in the pub and give him a terabyte of pad but afterwards he might be abroad for two years.

**Message Privacy**

Assuming you've solved the problems of generation and transmission, next comes actually encrypting your message. This is the most straightforward piece of the whole exercise.

You just work through your message a word at a time and logically XOR that word with a corresponding one from the pad. No part of the pad may be re-used under any circumstances. It's best to have your program destroy the read section of the pad after completing the encryption operation.

Decryption on the other end is exactly the same process. Simply logically XOR the cipher-text with the pad to recover the plain-text. This works because XOR is its own inverse:

A XOR B XOR B = A

**Message authenticity**

One of the things that trips up amateurs is that encrypting your data doesn't means that nobody can undetectably alter the message in transit.

Suppose that an ATM used the OTP to encrypt its communications but no authentication. I have £0 in my bank account but I ask the ATM to give me £500. The bank replies with a single bit message which indicates whether the withdrawal is authorised or not: 1 for yes, 0 for no.

I know the bank is going to decline me so at precisely the right moment, I *flip* the bit before it gets to the machine. The machine spits out the £500.

You get around this problem by having a message authentication code (MAC). This is an authentication code you tack on the end of the message which acts as a secure checksum.

If I tried to flip the bit on a message with a MAC protecting it, the checksum would not longer verify and the system would know something funny is going on.

To authenticate OTP messages, you probably want to use a [universal hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing). This allows you to retain the security proof on both the hash and the cipher-text.

Universal hashes are a whole series of questions and answer in their own right so I'm just going to say that you should read around the subject.

**Conclusion**

The OTP is one of these ciphers that lot of amateurs gravitate towards because it's "perfectly" secure.

However, in reality we don't deal with perfection. We often don't have a secure channel with which to communicate a pad. We often don't have an RNG that has a failure rate of fractions of a billion or trillion. There are often cockups that result in pad being re-used.

For all of these reasons, competent cryptographers never recommend an OTP.

Comment: "No part of the pad may be re-used under any circumstances." I think that's a bit misleading as written. It seems to imply that if you have two pads, P1 and P2, P2 can not contain any sub-sequences that appear in P1! That is clearly not correct. P2 will certainly contain subsequences that occur in P1 (if you define "subsequence" short enough). Am I being too pedantic?

Comment: This statement that "competent cryptographers never recommend an OTP" is not true at all.  And the statement about amateurs gravitating towards the OTP is misleading.  In point of fact, the OTP does have a function on our big round earth amongst serious, informed people, and it is used when they want to be assured of confidentiality.  The OTP still has a legitimate use in certain quarters.

Answer (score 2):

As well as Simon Johnson's suggestions you should think about the following:

- When collecting the entropy you'll need to ascertain the speed at which the hardware random number generator provides entropy. The collection program may need to be in a loop so waits for more entropy to become available (similar to /dev/random).
- Think about other sources of entropy you could mix in (don't have all your eggs in one basket).
- Use a [randomness extractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Von_Neumann_extractor) on the generated entropy to get a uniform distribution.
- Depending on what kind of data you are sending you could use fixed size data blocks and use padding to disguise the true length of the plaintext.
- You need a protocol. Think about which key gets used and when. How do you communicate which key to use for decrypting to the recipient. What do you do in failure. How do you compute the MAC, etc. Look up the [SSH protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253) for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The only really effective way of using OTPs is running a Numbers Station. Or at least relaying your message through a Numbers Station.

I would check out a document called ["Guide to Secure Communications using the One Time Pad"](http://users.telenet.be/d.rijmenants/papers/one_time_pad.pdf) (PDF) for proper CryptSec and OpSec procedures when it comes to using them in the field.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of nay sayers that refute the benefit of one time pads. It's a little like positing that matches are useless and must not even be contemplated because turbo lighters exist now.  I believe that matches are probably still sold somewhere.  More seriously, consider:-

- A blue sky figure of 4GB for a OTP is a little OTT.  When you need the security of a OTP, short messages of 100ish characters is what you'll be transmitting.  You can speculate on the nature of their content.  The ability to transmit 100 of these messages securely across national boundaries is sufficient.
- The reason you're alive posting this question is due to the negotiations during the Cuban Missile Crisis being successfully conducted via a OTP system.
- The reason I'm not posting this reply in German is due to agents in 1940's Europe communicating via OTPs.

If you set realistic expectations on your use of OTPs, with communication limited to a small number of nodes, take heart that they are proven to work pretty well.  A lot of that comms traffic still hasn't been de-crypted 70 years later and probably never will be due to the OTP's provable security.